# Make app not deliver notifications to Android Wear

Tags: java, android

I have an app I'm working on that isn't yet compatible with Wear.  Is there a way for me to block notifications from being delivered to a user's smart watch?  The app has a persistent notification that I do not want to display until the wear module is ready.

Answer (score 0):

If your using notification builder, there's an option to setLocalOnly.

Development docs :'setLocalOnly(boolean localOnly)
Set whether or not this notification should not bridge to other devices. '

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setLocalOnly(true)
     .build();
```

Not tested it from the phone but I know it works with stopping my wear notification appearing on the phone.